# When running Flask on local, how can I specify the reloader (stat instead of watchdog)

Tags: python, flask, watchdog

I am running a Flask application on local (Windows) using the `flask run` on command prompt. By default, the `stat` reloader is used, which works great for me. I have recently started using celery for a task queue. To get the celery worker to auto-reload I am using `watchmedo`, which required me to install `watchdog` in the virtual environment. Now Flask has automatically started using `watchdog` instead of `stat`, which causes unnecessary reloads i.e. reloading even when non-application python files (located outside the application root folder but in the environment folder) get updated.

[image]

I have 2 questions around this:

1. When using the `flask run` method to run the flask application, can I specify the reloader type to use (stat instead of watchdog).
2. If that's not possible, can I configure watchdog (that's automatically getting used) to ignore py/pyc files outside the application root folder?

Answer (score 1):

In short, yes, there is a way to specify "stat" instead of "watchdog".  All you need to do is set the `reloader_type` argument to "stat" in your `app.run()` call:

```py
app.run(
    debug=True, 
    use_reloader=True, 
    reloader_type="stat", # <-- Set the reloader_type!
    ...
)
```

Additional info:

The flask `app.run()` docs (https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/api/#flask.Flask.run) do not appear to explicitly mention this parameter, but they do reference additional docs on `werkzeug.serving.run_simple()` that have info on this argument: https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/serving/#reloader

To summarize the docs, the default value for `reloader_type` appears to be `auto`, which chooses the reloader type based on what is available on your system.  If watchdog is available, then flask will use watchdog.  (As in your original question, the user may have installed watchdog as a dependency required for celery task management.)  If watchdog is not installed, then flask will use the built-in stat reloader.  Setting the `reloader_type` to "watchdog" or "stat" forces the application to search for one or the other.

As an aside, in case anybody else stumbles upon this question, other reloader problems seem to appear as a result of using watchdog.  For example, I actually had a problem with flask *not reloading frequently enough* (as opposed to reloading *too often*, as the OP experienced).  So, if you are having any sort of issues with reloading when using watchdog, especially if the changes were introduced after installing watchdog to satisfy other packages' dependencies, try the fix mentioned above to swap stat in for watchdog.